# How to convert sum of ascii values of a string to base 36 in C#

Tags: c#, base36

In C# how can I convert the sum of ascii values of a string to base 36 ?

my string "P0123456789"

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to get the sum(ascii) of all characters in the string converted to base36

Comment: Have you tried to google `c# base36` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var s = "P0123456789";
var result = s.Sum(x => x);
var base36ed = ConvertToBase(result,36);
```

> *Output =  GT*

The method below was found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5babf71f-4375-40aa-971a-21c1f0b9762b/convert-from-decimalbase10-to-alphanumericbase36)

```
public String ConvertToBase(int num, int nbase)
{
String chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

// check if we can convert to another base
if(nbase < 2 || nbase > chars.Length)
    return "";

int r;
String newNumber = "";

// in r we have the offset of the char that was converted to the new base
while(num >= nbase)
{
    r = num % nbase;
    newNumber = chars[r] + newNumber;
    num = num / nbase;
}
// the last number to convert
newNumber = chars[num] + newNumber;

return newNumber;
}
```

Comment: That won't work, he wants it converted to base36 first. Also, the `ToCharArray` is redundant.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance - cheers for the feedback

Comment: I want the ascii sum added first and then convert the sum to base36.

Comment: @user961440 - The code above adds the ascii values together, then you can enter that number into that function.. `ConvertToBase(result,36);`

Comment: @user961440 you are a member of SO for ~2 years and don't know how it works?

Comment: @Sayse `ConvertToBase` ???

Comment: @I4V - The 'here' in my question is a link, there is a function in that link... I'll add it to my question...

Comment: can you modify the code and make it clear to me. what's x=>x ?

Comment: @user961440 - lambda expression... the top two lines returns a base 36'd string

Comment: @Sayse - I do know lambda expression but I did think the condition was incomplete.

Comment: @user961440 - Try it, its not incomplete, its summing the value of each letter

Comment: @I4V - Is SO teaching me base36 ?

Comment: @sayse - instead of using Convert.ToBase(int num,int nbase), I can use the existing Convert.ToString(result,36).right?

Comment: @user961440 -No, you will get an `ArgumentException` - Invalid base

Comment: @user961440 No SO teaches *how to ask a question*